# Need complete soap request to add localclaim under claims in wso2

Tags: soap, wso2, soapui, wso2-identity-server

I need to add some `localclaim`'s under claims in `wso2` using a SOAP request.

I have added the `localclaim` successfully but needs some fields in soap request

1. display Name
2. description
3. Supported by Default
4. Required
5. read only

Comment: I have read the docs and doing that but there is no complete soap request is available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Display Name, description, supported by Default, required and read-only attributes need to as claimProperties. Here is the sample SOAP request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:xsd1="http://dto.mgt.metadata.claim.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <xsd:addLocalClaim>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <xsd:localClaim>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <xsd1:attributeMappings>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xsd1:attributeName>email</xsd1:attributeName>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xsd1:userStoreDomain>primary</xsd1:userStoreDomain>
            </xsd1:attributeMappings>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->

               <xsd1:claimProperties>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <xsd1:propertyName>DisplayName</xsd1:propertyName>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <xsd1:propertyValue>email2</xsd1:propertyValue>
              </xsd1:claimProperties>
               <xsd1:claimProperties>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <xsd1:propertyName>Description</xsd1:propertyName>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <xsd1:propertyValue>email2 local cliam</xsd1:propertyValue>
              </xsd1:claimProperties>
               <xsd1:claimProperties>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <xsd1:propertyName>SupportedByDefault</xsd1:propertyName>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <xsd1:propertyValue>true</xsd1:propertyValue>
              </xsd1:claimProperties>
               <xsd1:claimProperties>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <xsd1:propertyName>Required</xsd1:propertyName>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <xsd1:propertyValue>true</xsd1:propertyValue>
              </xsd1:claimProperties>
               <xsd1:claimProperties>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <xsd1:propertyName>Required</xsd1:propertyName>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <xsd1:propertyValue>true</xsd1:propertyValue>
              </xsd1:claimProperties>
               <xsd1:claimProperties>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <xsd1:propertyName>ReadOnly</xsd1:propertyName>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <xsd1:propertyValue>true</xsd1:propertyValue>
              </xsd1:claimProperties>

            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd1:localClaimURI>http://example.org/email</xsd1:localClaimURI>
         </xsd:localClaim>
      </xsd:addLocalClaim>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```